# Small layout problem with refresh icon getting cut off

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, android-app

As you can see in the attached screen shot, on my Nexus 4 the refresh spinner (progress bar) arrow ends gets cut off. I suspect the view is smaller than the image.

[image]

Comment: I also noticed this and installed the sample app of the library that is used. I found the same behavior, so this bug in the library, not in the Stack Exchange app.

Comment: Since this bug report, [the pull to refresh behaviour has been changed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208581/152515) and replaced with a different library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We moved onto a new pull to refresh library which fixes this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it was caused by [this commit](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/commit/684a6166bdb3c5fbb82b2e4089ef37e9861ec0a6) in the PullToRefresh library. The refresh asset got cropped down to the exact bounds of the image, and since it's not square, it doesn't fit when rotated.

I've created updated assets that fix this that can be [downloaded here](https://db.tt/eAvLB2IY). Either:

a) Merge these with the `PullToRefresh` library `res` folder
 b) Put them in your project's local resources and set the `ptrDrawable` attribute on the `PullToRefreshListView` to reference them.