# Use ActionBar-PullToRefresh instead of Android-PullToRefresh

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

The app currently uses the library [Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) by Chris Banes. This library is officially discontinued for almost a year. It contains bugs that will not be fixed like this one in the Stack Exchange app: [Small layout problem with refresh icon getting cut off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194716/small-layout-problem-with-refresh-icon-getting-cut-off)

So my question is, why not use the modern **ActionBar**-PullToRefresh instead? This pattern is used by all Google apps that have refresh functionality, for example Google+, Gmail, Drive and Newsstand.

[image: ActionBar-PullToRefresh]

There is also an active library for this: [ActionBar-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh) by Chris Banes, the same developer.

Comment: ActionBar-PullToRefresh is currently in preview state... but so is the SE Android app.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Should this be marked as [status-complete] now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 3/12/14**:

As of version 1.0.20 of the Android application we now use ActionBar-PullToRefresh in the app, giving a nicer refresh UI everywhere.

[image]

---

We will eventually do this, however we have higher priorities at the moment.

Comment: Looks like this is [status-completed] in v1.0.21?

Comment: @StevenV Yep, I was waiting to get near a device to take a screenshot before I edited this.